# Combinations of selecting $n$ objects with $k$ different types

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that I am buying cakes for a party. There are $k$ different types and I intend to buy a total of $n$ cakes. How many different combinations of cakes could I possibly bring to the party?

Comment: Seeded question

Comment: PS. This problem has a really nice proof. I'm pretty hopeful that someone else has seen it posts it

Comment: Whenever I do this sort of thing, the shop runs out of the cakes I want.

Comment: Classic stars and bars problem.  It's also equivalent to the number of ways to distribute n identical pieces of candy to k children or putting n identical balls into k urns or the number of terms in the expansion of (x_1+...+x_k)^n.

Comment: voting to close--because I'd do so if I saw it as a real question--no indication the asker has thought about the problem first.

Comment: @Katie: Its a perfectly valid question and I haven't seen a hasn't thought about it close reason on any of the other SO websites (maybe mathoverflow is different though). If you want someone to think about a problem, the best solution is to just not give them the whole solution. For example, show them how you go about proving it and leave out the actual formula

Comment: well, when we've been discussing hw questions the consensus has been that questions that could be straight hw problems should include some attempt at a solution or point where the asker is stuck. No, there's not a "hasn't thought about it" reason to close on other SO sites, but the way we've been discussing hw questions, the ones that are straight problems will get closed. (at least, I'd leave a comment asking the author to edit with more detail before I answered, and if they didn't after a few days I'd vote to close.) See several meta discussions for more on this; there is debate, of course

Comment: @Katie: The problem with "homework" questions is that that the site gets clogged up with extremely specific and almost identical questions and people waste time answering the same question repeatedly. Questions which are general like this avoid most of these problems. If you are worried that the asker is just avoiding their homework, the answer is already on the Internet for questions like this anyway.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using a method that's often called "stars and bars":

We draw $n$ stars in a row to represent the cakes, and $k-1$ bars to divide them up. All of the stars to the left of the first bar are cakes of the first type; stars between the first two bars are of the second type; . . . .

```
**|***||*|
```

Here's an example with $n=6$ and $k=5$. We're getting 2 of the first type, 3 of the second type, 0 of the third type, 1 of the fourth type, and 0 of the fifth type.

In order to solve the problem, we just need to reorder the stars and bars by choosing the $k-1$ spots for the bars out of the $n+k-1$ total spots, so our answer is:

$$ \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}. $$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Note that $\binom {n+k-1}{k-1} = \binom {n+k-1}{n}$ - here the description picks the $k-1$ spots for the bars - equivalently we could pick the $n$ spots for the cakes.

Comment: Here is a [derivation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542152/about-counting-number-of-n-tuples) of your formula using the Polya Enumeration Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Let g(n,k) = # combinations of cakes.

Notice that:

- g(n,1) = 1. (all the cakes are the same)
- g(n,2) = n+1. (e.g. for 5 cakes, the # of cakes of type 1 can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- g(1,k) = k.
- g(2,k) = k*(k-1)/2 + k (the first term is two different cakes; the second term is when both cakes are the same), as long as k > 1. (otherwise g(2,1) = 1)
- g(3,k) = k * (k-1) * (k-2)/6 + k*(k-1)/2 * 2 + k (the first term is 3 different cakes; the second term is 2 different cakes, with a *2 since there are two choices for which one to duplicate, the third term is when all 3 cakes are the same), as long as k > 2.

If we think of k as a radix rather than the # of cakes, then this problem is equivalent to expressing the # of distinct n-digit numbers in base k whose digits are in sorted order. (e.g. 1122399 is equivalent to 9921231)

I *think* I can express it as a nonrecursive sum:

g(n,k) = sum from j=1 to max(n,k) of { (k choose j) * h(n,j) }

where h(n,j) is the # of ways to partition N cakes using j different types. (the term in the sum is when there are j distinct cakes actually chosen.)

But that's about as far as I can get... :/

---

edit: looks like it's [combinations with repetitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) = ((k+n-1) choose n). (same as the wikipedia article with n and k swapped)

Comment: nice solution Jason S...............

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have $n$ items and $k$ bins. You need $k-1$ separators to get the $n$ items into the $k$ bins. There are $(n + k - 1)!$ permutations of ordering $n$ items and $(k-1)$ separators. The permutations of the $n$ items don't matter, and the permutations of the $(k-1)$ separators don't matter, so you'll need to divide by $n!$ and $(k-1)!$

Thus you have $$\frac{(n + k - 1)!}{n!(k-1)!} = \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since cakes are involved, I shall solve it using what's called the  **"ice-cream parlour"** approach.

For each of the $k$ types, go on saying **yes, yes, yes...** until you don't want any more, and then say **no** and move on to the next type.

Of course, you may say **no** straight away to any type if you don't want it, and you don't need to say **no** after the $k^{th}$ type because there is no next type.

So there will be $n$ of **yes** and $(k-1)$ of **no** whichever way you choose, and the only decision you need to take is where to place the **no's** in the string of $(n+k-1)$ responses,

thus $\dbinom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ different combinations of cakes.