# German combinatoric terms vs English terms

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, terminology, combinations

I'm a German Computer Science student and I currently work with combinatorics as part of my curriculum. I wanted to research combinatorics in English but I'm confused about the terminology.

In German classes, I'm taught there are 6 *main events* in combinatorics:

1. Permutation without repetition: $n!$
2. Permutation with repetition: $\frac{n}{k_1 \cdot k_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot k_n}$
3. Variation without repetition: $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$
4. Variation with repetition: $n^k$
5. Combination without repetition: $\binom{n}{k}$
6. Combination with repetition: $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

What is the English (accepted) terminology for each of those operations?

Comment: Is the formula for permutation with repetition supposed to read $$\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2! \cdot \ldots \cdot k_n!}$$ where $k_1 + k_2 + \cdots + k_n = n$?

Comment: Do you mean, how do we say them? For example $n!$= "n factorial". Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ elements.

*e.g.* $\{1,2,3\}~~n \leftarrow 3$

## 1. Permutations ($n!$)

#### Ordered without repetition.

Also called (re-)**arrangement**, (re-)ordering or **substitutions**.

> The "passive" way to regard a permutation of the set S is an **ordered arrangement** (or **listing**, or **linearly ordered arrangement**, or **sequence without repetition**) of the elements of S

That would be the bijections from $S$ to itself.

*e.g.* $\{(1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,3), (3,2,1), (2,3,1), (3,1,2)\}$ (each can be found in $S^n$)

## 2. multiset permutations ($\frac{n!}{\prod{k_i!}}$)

**Ordered** but with "limited" **repetitions** :

> if $M$ is a finite multiset, then a multiset permutation is an **ordered** **arrangement** of elements of $M$ in which each element appears exactly as often as is its multiplicity in $M$.

*e.g.* with $M=\{1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3\}$ we would have $(k_1,k_2,k_3)\leftarrow(2,1,3)$ and therefore the number of possible multiset permutations would be $\frac{Card(M)!}{k_1!.k_2!.k_3!}=\frac{6!}{2!1!3!}$

$$\text{let} (k_1,k_2,\dots,k_i) \in (\mathbb{N}^*)^i ~~~~ \sum_{p=1}^{i}{k_p} = n$$
the number of multiset permutations is $$\frac{|M|!}{\prod_{p=1}^{i}{k_p!}}$$

## 3. k-permutations ($\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$)

#### Ordered without repetition

"Weaker" than permutations, it is ordered but with the number of chosen elements being $k\leqslant n$

> These are not permutations except in special cases, but are natural generalizations of the ordered arrangement concept.

*e.g.* for $k\leftarrow 2$ : {(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)}
(each can be found in $S^k$)

> Sometimes called **variations** in the older literature, these objects are also known as **partial permutations** or as **sequences without repetition**, terms that avoid confusion with the other, more common, meaning of "permutation"

`0 if k > n`

## 4. k-tuples ($n^k$)

#### Ordered with repetition

**Ordered arrangements** of length k of the elements of a set $S$ where repetition is allowed are called **k-tuples**, but have sometimes been referred to as **permutations with repetition** although they are not permutations in general. They are also called **words** over the alphabet $S$ in some contexts.

> A k-tuple is a **sequence** (or **ordered list**) of k elements ($k\in\mathbb{N}$)

*e.g.* for $k\leftarrow 2 : \{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)\}$

I personally see it as writing in base $n$ with the character set $S$

## 5. k-combinations ($\binom{n}{k}$)

#### Unordered without repetition

> combination is a way of selecting items from a collection, such that (unlike permutations) the order of selection does not matter.
>   A **k-combination** of a set $S$ is a subset of k distinct elements of $S$.

`0 if k > n`

## 6. k-multicombination ($\binom{n+k-1}{k}$)

#### Unordered with repetition

**k-combination with repetitions** or **k-multicombination**, or **multisubset**

> Combinations refer to the combination of n things taken k at a time without repetition. To refer to combinations in which repetition is allowed, the terms **k-selection**, **k-multiset**, or **k-combination with repetition** are often used.

## Sum Up

```
|            | Ordered                    | Unordered          |
|------------|----------------------------|--------------------|
| Repetition | k-tuples                   | k-multicombination |
| Uniqueness | permutation, k-permutation | k-combinations     |
```

## Source

[Wikipedia/Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and [Wikipedia/Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Comment: Great Explanation, for completeness I want to mention *multiset combinations*, which are the unordered counterpart to multiset permutations, you can see them [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217308/combinations-of-multisets-the-theory)

Answer (score 2):

From [Combinatorics: A Guided Tour](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857626)

[image]

If you want to know how to say each:

$n^k$: n to the k

$n!$: n factorial

$(n)_k$: n falling k

$n \choose k$: n choose k

$\left(\! {n \choose k} \!\right)={{k+n-1} \choose k}$: n multi-choose k

$S(n,k)={n \brace k}$: n Stirling k