# How to not use stars and bars to solve unordered sampling with replacement?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics

Say I want to find the number of different ways of unordered sampling **k** elements from **n** distinguishable elements with replacement, and a common way is to use the method of **[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))**. Although this is artful and easy to understand, I want to know whether there are other methods to solve this problem, and if there are, what are those methods? And the more direct, the rawer, the better!

BTW, I have searched in a few textbooks on this problem, and it seems all of them are using the above method.

Comment: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/542212/12042) Marko Riedel gives a proof using the [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pólya_enumeration_theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you multiply out $(1+x+x^2+\ldots)^n$ distributively then you get a term $x^{k_1}x^{k_2}\>\cdots\> x^{k_n}$ for each independent sampling of a term  in each of the factors. Collecting terms according to increasing powers of $x$ we obtain a formal series $\sum_{k\geq0} a_k\>x^k$, whereby $a_k$ counts the number of samplings $(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$ with $k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_n=k$.

Now
$$(1+x+x^2+\ldots)^n={1\over (1-x)^n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-n\choose k} (-x)^k$$
(binomial series). It follows that
$$a_k=(-1)^k{-n\choose k}={n+k-1\choose k}\ .$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution using generating function!