# Unique ways to paint N identical balls with K disticnt colors.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm wondering how many ways you can paint n identical balls with k distinct colors.

I'm thinking of it as finding all possible sets of positive intergers solution to the equation

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+...+x_k=n$$

But that's where I'm stuck atm

Comment: The stars and bars argument leads to the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Must you use all k colors each time?  Are all $x_i>0$?

Comment: No, you just have to use at least 1 color

Comment: Also, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686/combinations-of-selecting-n-objects-with-k-different-types

Comment: So I read the 2nd theorem proof but was unable to understand the intuition. Could you explain it?

Comment: So the $x_i$ are non-negative, not positive...

Answer (score 1):

(This ***is*** Stars and Bars, just dissected a little.)

Take your $n$ identical balls and $k-1$ identical dividers, and arrange them in a row. This can be done in N ways:$$N=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{n! \cdot (k-1)!}$$bearing in mind that there are two sets of **identical** items.

Ues Color $\#1$ for the first section (up to the first divider), Color $\#2$ for the next section, and so on. This allows two or more dividers to come together, which deals with the "not this color" situation...