# Combination problem: retrieve four kinds of objects with restriction

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to select (combinations) $n$ objects from $a$ identical  objects of first kind, $b$ identical  objects of second kind, $c$ identical  objects of third kind and  $d$ identical objects of fourth kind?
P.S. : Since the maximum number of any kind is restricted it is different from the original stars and bars problem where there is no restriction.

Comment: Don't you mean "d identical objects of fourth kind"?

Comment: yes,thank you.I have corrected it.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686/combinations-of-selecting-n-objects-with-k-different-types

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid thankyou,the answers almost the same concept

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. The question same as,

The total no of non negative  integral solutions of x+y+z+w=n , where,

$0\le x\le a,0\le y\le b\ ,\ 0 \le z\le c\ $ and $\ 0\le w\le d$

changing variables as,
x1=a-x,y1=a-y,z1=a-z and w1=a-w,

we get the answer to be,
number of solutions of the equation x1+y1+z1+w1=a+b+c+d-n

answer= $$\binom{a+b+c+d-n+4-1}{4-1}$$